# How to run a non-linear autoregression with exogenous inputs with sysidentpy?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, neural-network

I am trying to run a nonlinear autoregression with exogenous inputs (NARX) in Python.

This is my code

Step 1: import the libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sysidentpy.model_structure_selection import FROLS
from sysidentpy.basis_function import Polynomial, Fourier
from sysidentpy.metrics import root_relative_squared_error
from sysidentpy.utils.generate_data import get_siso_data
from sysidentpy.utils.display_results import results
from sysidentpy.utils.plotting import plot_residues_correlation, plot_results
from sysidentpy.residues.residues_correlation import compute_residues_autocorrelation, compute_cross_correlation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Step 2: import the data

```
df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Action\Downloads\Python\Practice_Data\sorted_data v2.xlsx")
```

Step 3: Organize the data

```
target_column = ['public health care services'] 
predictors = list(set(list(df.columns))-set(target_column))
df[predictors] = df[predictors]/df[predictors].max()
```

Step 4: Step up the training and testing data

```
X = df[predictors].values
y = df[target_column].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=40)
print(X_train.shape); print(X_test.shape)
```

Step 5: Create the NARX Neural Network Model

```
basis_function = Polynomial(degree=2)
model = FROLS(
    basis_function=basis_function,
    order_selection=True,
    n_info_values=10,
    extended_least_squares=False,
    ylag=2, xlag=2,
    info_criteria='aic',
    estimator='least_squares',
)
```

Step 6: Apply fit the model

```
 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

From step 6 I am experiencing an error

TypeError: fit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Step 7: Prediction

```
yhat = model.predict(X_test, y_test)
```

I am also experiencing an error

AttributeError: 'FROLS' object has no attribute 'final_model'

Step 8: Compute the RRSE

```
rrse = root_relative_squared_error(y_test, yhat)
print(rrse)
```

I am experiencing the following error

NameError: name 'yhat' is not defined

Well, I realise that this error is due to the error before it, so 'yhat' is not defined.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? can U share?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of SysIdentPy and just found this question.

I hope you already solved it, but if not, here is the solution:

The first error you got

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
TypeError: fit() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

is due the fact you have to use keyword arguments instead of positional arguments. To fix it, just use:

```
model.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
```

All the other problems are consequences of the first one: without fiting the model you cannot predict and you will not have a final_model to access, for example.

I'll add a "check_fitted" method to give the users a more detailed message about this kind of error.

The use of keyword arguments instead of positional arguments was described in update v0.17.0 and the examples were adapted to follow this change in this same update, but this can be a common mistake and hard to understand without a propor error message if you havent read the docs.

Note: Its not related to your question, but you used the train_test_split method from sklearn to split your data. In a time series scenario this is usually (to not say always) wrong. I don't know what you were trying to do, but its worth checking this part too (take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html)

Hope it helps you.